# Should team leader engage with team or separate themselves?

Tags: team, team-building, teamleader

I have team of 6. As their Software development TL should I always be with team in their joy and cry or should I separate myself from them? Observed that, if I be with their team, they tends to fear less to me.

Comment: Which culture are you from as expected management style , norms, and social expectations differ based on the culture and country?

Comment: How can you be a team leader if you don't engage with your team?

Comment: Different teams and situations are going to require different approaches.

Comment: If you want your team to fear you, you're not much of a leader

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reading your other question, I understand you are new to leadership, so based on that:

**1. Get some training**

Like any other skill, leading people can be learned and taught. Much is made of certain people being 'natural leaders'. Please understand that this is not most of us. Speak to your boss and make the case for leadership training, it will benefit you all in the long term.

**2. The Team Leader is part of the team**

How you work with the team is up to you, that is part of how you develop your management and leadership style, but you are part of the team. To use sporting terminology the captain of a football (soccer) team does not stand apart from the team, they are part of it, but they provide leadership and direction. That's you.

**3. Fear is a very difficult management tool to use effectively**

> Observed that, if I be with their team, they tends to fear less to me.

Why should your team fear you? Respect you, yes absolutely. To continue the analogy above, how many football(soccer) teams do you think live in fear of the team captain? This may be dependent on local culture, or it may be a "lost in translation" issue, but if I were you I'd focus less on people fearing you and more on working to earn their respect.